# Haskell non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use this simple function from this page: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/2

But when I use it I got the non-exhaustive patterns error.The Code.

```
-- return one but last
lastButOne [x,_]  = x
lastButone (_:xs) = lastButOne xs
```

And I call it like this:

```
lastButOne [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `lastButone` on your second line but you mean `lastButOne`. Whoops! :)

Comment: hmm... we need `-Wcase-sensitive-shadow`

Comment: @DanielWagner: `-Wall` already warns about declarations without type signatures, so this shouldn't be a problem most of the time. I don't know if `-W` does; it'd be nice to have a decent set of warnings on by default...